# Back-propagation exhibiting quadratic memory consumption

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm running into a weird problem with TensorFlow. I've set up a very simple classification problem, four input variables, one binary output variable, one layer of weights and bias, output goes through a sigmoid to 0 or 1.

The problem is, memory consumption is quadratic in the number of records of training data! With only 5,000 records, it's already 900 megabytes; at 10,000, it runs into a few gigabytes. Since I want to end up using at least a few tens of thousands of records, this is a problem.

It is happening specifically in the back propagation step; when I just try to evaluate the cost function, memory consumption is linear in the number of records, as expected.

Code follows. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import psutil
import tensorflow as tf
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
random_seed = 1
tf.set_random_seed(random_seed)

# Data
data = np.loadtxt('train.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
train_X = data[:, :-1]
train_Y = data[:, -1]

rows = np.shape(train_X)[0]
cols = np.shape(train_X)[1]

# Inputs and outputs
X = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=(rows, cols))
Y = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=rows,)

# Weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((cols, 1)))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(()))

# Model
p = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)
cost = tf.reduce_sum((p-Y)**2/rows)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# Just one optimizer step is enough to demonstrate the problem
optimizer.run({X: train_X, Y: train_Y})

# Memory consumption is quadratic in number of rows
print('{0:,} bytes'.format(process.memory_info().peak_wset))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be again the problem of shape. Using matmul the way I did there, generates output of shape (n,1). Using that in a context where shape (n,) was expected, silently generates quadratic blowup.

The solution is squeeze. Specifically, `tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(X, W))`.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that memory consumption blows up like that since the backprop requires the extra memory to keep track of the gradients of each operation (though I can't figure out how it ends up being quadratic).

### Solution : Mini-batches

This is usually the goto method when it comes to training models. Split up your training data into little mini-batches each containing a fixed number of samples (this is rarely more than 200 samples) at feed it to the optimizer one mini-batch at a time. So if your `batch_size=64` then the `train_X` and `train_Y` fed to the optimizer will be of the shapes `(64, 4)` and `(64,)` respectively.

I would try something like this

```
batch_size = 64
for i in range(rows):
    batch_X = train_X[i*batch_size : (i + 1)*batch_size]
    batch_Y = train_Y[i*batch_size : (i + 1)*batch_size]

    optimizer.run({X: batch_X, Y:batch_Y})
```